# Page is defaulting to archive page and not designated template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, custom-post-type-archives, archives

1. I created a page called "Projects" through the wordpress admin
2. I created a template called "Projects"
3. Set the "Projects" page to use the Projects template.

How come when I navigate to the Projects page it shows the archive page and not the Projects template.

Also, if I set the "posts page" in settings->reading to "Projects" in the admin then the above happens. But, if I don't set a post page then I can go to the /Projects and this works fine. However, if I go to /projects (lowercase) then this doesn't work and it defaults to the archive page.

I'm confused as to what is going on, can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This conflict normally happens when a custom post type archive and a normal wordpress page has the same slug. The custom post type archive has the higher priority here.

If you have a custom post type by the name 'Projects' and 'has_archive' is set to true for the custom post type then the conflict will arise. Set 'has_archive' to false so that it shows the page template. Or you could also create a archive-[post-type].php and style it in accordance with your portfolio page template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CPT UI, you can change the archive slug:
[image: archive conflict with page wordpress]

Or if you're using register_post_type(), add this:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products-archive' ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my custom-post was with a slug "projects" and the slug of my projects was "2016", "2017" or "2018", single projects were not reachable ( ex: /projects/2017 ) and go directly to the custom post type archive,

After changing the slug of the project to "project-2017", projects were reachable ...

I think there is a conflict when the slug is only a number ...

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the issue on my committees' page, I also had a post-type committee with the same slug. Changing the slug of the page or post type will resolve your problem and also you can change has_archive => false.

```
<i>    register_post_type( 'committies',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Committees ' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Committees ' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-users',
            'has_archive' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'committie'),
            **'show_in_rest' => true,**
            'supports'            => array( 'title',   'thumbnail',  'revisions',    ),
  
        )
    );</i>
```